# Meta refresh issue with URL for parent window in firefox

Tags: php, javascript, session, logout

In my site, header contains logout section for twitter. Three files are used in these logout functionality. When the user click logout, it opens the twitter logout URL and the parent window refreshe and goes to index page in chrome.

But the parent window does not refresh in firefox. Even after the session destroy, it shows logout and if we refresh the page manual it shows sign in. Anybody can help me to solve this problem

**Header.php**

```
<li><a href="javascript:;"  onclick="opennewwindow(); clearsession();">Logout</a></li>

function opennewwindow()
{
    var mywin=window.open('twitlogout.php','chindhu','width=550,height=350');
}

function clearsession()
{
var req = GetXmlHttpObject();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(req.readyState == 1) {
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>';
}   
 if (req.readyState == 4 ) {
     if( req.status == 200) {
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=req.responseText;
} 
else
{
alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
}
 } 
}  
req.open("GET", "clearsession.php", true);
req.send(null);
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    return null;
}
```

**twitlogout.php**

```
<?php
include("header.php");
header("Location:https://twitter.com/#!/logout"); 
?>
```

**clearsession.php**

```
<?php include("config/dbconfig.php");?> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<?php echo URLPATH;?>">

<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['id']);
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['oauth_provider']);
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the result of the `clearsession.php` to the status element. The meta property refresh needs to be in the header, so that might be why its never called.

The best way to force javascript to reload the page is to use `window.location.reload();`. You can put that at the following location:

```
if( req.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=req.responseText;
  setTimeout(window.location.reload, 2000); //reload after two seconds
}
```

I am using a timeout of two seconds before the reload, but you can set it to whatever you want.

Comment: Yes. Now its working fine. Thanks for the answer. +1 for the great answer

Answer (score 0):

Also we can just add the "window.location='our file'" within the function. But a disadvantage is it shows the URL when the clearsession.php is called within the function

```
function clearsession()
    {

            window.location="clearsession.php";

    }
```